# Konqueror: no sound with text to speech

Tags: kde, text-to-speech, konqueror

Yesterday morning when I had Konqueror open and pointing at a text file. Clicking on **Tools**, then clicking on the *SPeak Text* dropdown; gave me a very quick/rushed voice. Now doing the same results in no voice.

(I have a hit that this may have something to do with "D-Bus.")

Comment: What is your KDE/'buntu version ?

Answer (score 0):

**Jovie - KDE Text To Speech Daemon**
(based KDE 4.10.5 - 'buntu 13.04)

The Jovie: http://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/jovie/

The Jovie handbook online: http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdeaccessibility/jovie/

If the Jovie is installed then you should have the handbook.

[image]

If the Jovie is running then the Konqueror 'Speak Text' action should work. That is - if the Speech Dispatcher is working !

[image]

If the Jovie is not running then there is an error message.

[image]

To diagnose the Speech Dispatcher start the spd-conf with the '-d' option:

```
:~$ spd-conf -help
Usage: spd-conf [options]
A simple dialog based tool for basic configuration of Speech Dispatcher
and problem diagnostics.

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s, --test-spd-say    Test connection to Speech Dispatcher using spd-say
  -d, --diagnostics     Diagnose problems with the current setup
  -e, --espeak          Use espeak to synthesize messages
  -u, --create-user-conf
                        Create Speech Dispatcher configuration for the given
                        user
  --test-espeak         Test whether Espeak works as a standalone binary
  -c, --config-basic-settings-user
                        Configure basic settings in user configuration
  -D, --debug           Debug a problem and generate a report
  --test-alsa           Test ALSA audio
  -C, --config-basic-settings-system
                        Configure basic settings in system-wide configuration
  --test-pulse          Test Pulse Audio
  -n, --dont-ask        Do not ask any questions, allways use default values
  --test-festival       Test whether Festival works as a server
```

The spd-conf is part of the package: python3-speechd.